# how to get system's overflow icon?

Tags: android

I want to use the overflow icon in a dialog just like this:

[image]

So, is there a way to directly refer to this icon like android.R.drawable.xxx?
Or some other ways to achieve this goal?

By the way, I have searched this website and I couldn’t find this icon(I want the "round" point, not "rectangle").
https://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html

Anyone can help me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can get the icons from http://www.icons4android.com/

Answer (score 0):

Load images of overflow icon (called dots-vertical by google) from the following resource and enjoy

https://materialdesignicons.com/